# Seeking tool/algorithm for assigning code to Enumeration Areas (polygons) using serpentine numbering method?

Tags: serpentine, numbering, enumeration-areas

One of the projects I am working on has asked me to assign a code (starting from 1 and counting up) to polygons that represent enumeration areas so the statistician can sample the areas. I have been asked that the assigning of the code uses a serpentine numbering method. The image below shows an example of what I am trying to achieve. You start in the North West part of the area and snake bank and forth assigning numbers.

[image: Example]

Now I've searched various sites to see if anyone had developed a tool or even an algorithm that could be implemented that would achieve this. All I have found are numerous powerpoint slides and pdf files that simply say they have used serpentine numbering. I can only assume they have done this manually.

Does anyone know of an existing tool that would take a shapefile and number as described?

It seems to me that someone may have attempted this before but I have not been successful in finding a suitable reference as I don't usually get involved in census type data processing.

Comment: There's already a question/answer out there that addresses this.  It involved binning using PostgreSQL and allocating in order by bin.

Comment: @Vince, please don't make me beg! :) If I type into the search box on GIS SE "serpentine postgresql" I do not find the Q&A you are referring too.  Could you please post the link to it?

Comment: It's hard to find stuff from a phone, so I don't bother. I think a variant on [this](http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/73978/how-to-number-polygons-according-to-their-spatial-relationships) would work for you... My search was "postgresql order label" .
Getting the serpentine would require a modulus for direction across the scanline.

Comment: I'm starting to think this problem of serpentine numbering can be abstracted away to some sort of "[Hamiltonian path](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hamiltonian_path)". I just need a maths genius to step in? ;)

Comment: Shouldn't be a big deal.  Capture labels with X & Y values. Use Y scanlines of 5-20% of the height. Sort points in each Y row by X, with a modulus of Y row to control direction.  Viola.

Comment: @Vince, So I have a featureclass with contiguous polygons, I choose for example a "scanline" height that slices the dataset into 5 rows. I get polygon centroids for each row and sort by X. What do you mean by "with a modulus of Y row to control direction", can you show a simple example of what you were thinking?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Assume 5 rows with five gridded polygons for each row.  Further assume each row of height 1 and each polygon of width 1, with centroids at the physical centers, sequentially named "A" through "Y" in random order:

[image: unordered]

The query to grid the cells in this table (ArcGIS 10.2 geodatabase in PostgreSQL with SDE.ST_GEOMETRY) would be:

```
SELECT floor(sde.ST_MaxY(shape)) as ycell,
       floor(sde.ST_MinX(shape) + sde.ST_MaxX(shape) / 2.0) as xcell,
       objectid
FROM   polytab
```

And the code to label top-to-bottom, left to right would be:

```
UPDATE polytab SET seq_order = vtab.rownum
FROM 
(   SELECT row_number()
        over (order by ycell desc, xcell) as rownum, fkey
    FROM 
    (   SELECT floor(sde.ST_MaxY(shape)) as ycell,
               floor(sde.ST_MinX(shape) + sde.ST_MaxX(shape) / 2.0) as xcell,
               objectid as fkey
        FROM   polytab
    ) AS vpoly
) AS vtab
WHERE polytab.objectid = vtab.fkey;
```

Which would result in:

[image: scanline order]

So far, this is the same solution as in the [previous question](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/73978/how-to-number-polygons-according-to-their-spatial-relationships), but now we break new ground: In order to "reverse the polarity" on **even** scanlines, a modulus function can be used to alter the "xcell" values, based on whether "ycell modulus 2" is one or zero:

```
UPDATE polytab SET serp_order = vtab.rownum
FROM 
(   SELECT row_number()
        over (order by ycell desc, xcell) as rownum, fkey
    FROM 
    (   SELECT floor(sde.ST_MaxY(shape)) as ycell,
                (floor(sde.ST_MinX(shape) + sde.ST_MaxX(shape) / 2.0) *
            (cast(floor(sde.ST_MaxY(shape)) as integer) % 2) +
                (5 - floor(sde.ST_MinX(shape) + sde.ST_MaxX(shape) / 2.0)) *
            (cast((1 + floor(sde.ST_MaxY(shape))) as integer) % 2)) as xcell,
                objectid as fkey
        FROM   polytab
    ) AS vpoly
) AS vtab
WHERE polytab.objectid = vtab.fkey;
```

(As you can see, modulus operations must be integer, so the terms start to get unwieldy as a CAST is necessary; also note that the width is hard-coded as "5").

Now the labels are:

[image: serpentine order]

Porting this to an application which works with a generic file geodatabase is left as an exercise.

Comment: Wow! Math Guru or database God, how would you like to be acknowledged? :)

Comment: 't'weren't nothin', really.  The only pain was in the CAST syntax and balancing all those parenthesis.