# Sorting polygons into a n x n spatial array

Tags: postgis, polygon, array, sorting

I have a square group of contiguous polygons:

[image]

By using the centroid coordinates of each polygon, I want to assign each polygon's spatial sequence in a row by row fashion:

[image]

I have tried this PostgreSQL statement:

```
select id,st_centroid(geom) as center  
from work.qtrs_in_section 
order by st_y(st_centroid(geom)),st_x(st_centroid(geom));
```

It does give me groups of sorted y-values, but the x-values are not sorted in each row group:

[image]

Ideas?

Comment: The first step in [this answer](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/176197/seeking-tool-algorithm-for-assigning-code-to-enumeration-areas-polygons-using/176714#176714) generates the numbering scheme you want. You just need to strip off the "`sde.`" naming.

Comment: A great answer, Vince, thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As the centroids are not exactly (to the atomic level) aligned in a perfect North-South / East-West grid, you need to allow some displacement: if the points longitude/latitude are within X meters (cm, km, whatever) from each other, consider they are aligned.

For rectangular cell, don't bother with the centroid but you can use directly the min X or Y coordinate. Else you can replace `st_minY(geom)` by `st_y(st_centroid(geom))`

```
select *, 
      ROW_NUMBER() OVER(
       ORDER BY round(ST_MinY(geom)/50) desc, 
                ST_MinX(geom) asc
      ) as newID
FROM Grid
```

Note that I haven't used `floor` or `ceil` but I have rounded the coordinates divided by my distance of tolerance. This is done so `199.99` and `200.00`, as well as `149.99` and `150.00` are considered the same, but `100.01` and `199.99` are considered different.

You may need to play a bit with this tolerance to find the perfect one if the grid cells have different sizes.

Comment: Perfect! Plus another SQL technique added to my knowledgebase.

Comment: Technically, you only need one `round` operator, since once the rows are binned, binning the last ORDER BY term (columns) is unnecessary.

Comment: @Vince Good catch, thanks! I have edited accordingly