# Creating a snake-like labelling pattern with sequential numbers (ArcPy)

Tags: python, arcpy

I am new to Python and ArcPy.

I've got rows of points that go up in sequential number starting from the left to right. I need every second row to be flipped so that it goes right to left. Every point has an ID field denoting what row it belongs to (ORIG_FID). I can't figure out how to select that value in order to flip it. I'll also need to get the highest value in that particular row and plug it into pStart. Here is what I have:
[image: It will change every time as it is based on the polygon but this is what the data looks like]

```
def unique_values(table, field):
with arcpy.da.SearchCursor(table, [field]) as cursor:
    return sorted([{row[0] for row in cursor}])

values = unique_values(cruise_points, "ORIG_FID")


with arcpy.da.SearchCursor(cruise_points, "ORIG_FID") as cursor:
    for row in cursor:
        if (row[] % 2) != 0:
            select = arcpy.SelectLayerByAttribute_management("cruiselyr", "NEW_SELECTION", ' "ORIG_FID" = unique[]')
            codeblock = ('\n'
                         'rec = 0\n'
                         'def autoIncrement():\n'
                         '    global rec\n'
                         '    pStart = 12\n'  # HIGHEST VALUE IN THE ROW
                         '    pInterval = -1\n'
                         '    if (rec == 0):\n'
                         '        rec = pStart\n'
                         '    else:\n'
                         '        rec += pInterval\n'
                         '    return rec ')
            arcpy.CalculateField_management(select, "Label", "autoIncrement()", "PYTHON_9.3", codeblock)
```

Comment: Welcome to GIS SE. It would be helpful to include an example of your desired output.

Comment: @BERA the data will change every time as it's based on the polygon. That's why i'm trying to script it. but yes the 7 to 12 should be reversed.

Comment: @BERA exactly :). and I can, this is the last step in the script, but I'd rather have it automatic if I can.

Comment: I enveloped a polygon around it based on the spatial, got the x and y line from that, generated points along the y line at a set distance, made multiple x lines off those points, generated points on those x lines the set distance, and clipped out the points that aren't in the polygon. I don't mind sharing the script if you care to check it out.

Comment: Everyone else before me did all that manually each time lol

Comment: Check out my q&a on [serpentine numbering](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/176197/seeking-tool-algorithm-for-assigning-code-to-enumeration-areas-polygons-using?r=SearchResults) which is what you are describing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would probably switch to using cursors only instead of using CalculateField, which is generally harder to debug for anything reasonably complex.
Sounds like you're on a good track with the logic, though.  Kind of an interesting programming exercise.

Here's an approach with a toy example:

- Step through each value, count how large each row is
- Step through each value

  - If it's a new row, check if it's an even or odd row

    - If even, new labels will count upwards.  Reset the counting position to the end of the previous row
    - If odd, new labels will count downwards. Set the counting position to the end of this current row

```
from collections import defaultdict

row_ids = [2,2,2,2,2,2,3,3,3,3,3,3,4,4,4,4,4,5,5,5,5,5,6,6,6,6,6,6,6,6,6,6,6,7,7,7]

row_size = defaultdict(int)
for row_this in row_ids:
    row_size[row_this] += 1


label = 1
row_last = None

for row_this in row_ids:
    if row_this != row_last:
        if (row_this % 2) == 0:
            label_step = 1
            label += row_size[row_last] - 1
        else:
            label_step = -1
            label += row_size[row_this] + 1

    row_last = row_this
    label += label_step

    print(row_this, label)
```

Will give:

```
(2, 1)
(2, 2)
(2, 3)
(2, 4)
(2, 5)
(2, 6)
(3, 12)
(3, 11)
(3, 10)
(3, 9)
(3, 8)
(3, 7)
(4, 13)
(4, 14)
(4, 15)
(4, 16)
(4, 17)
(5, 22)
(5, 21)
(5, 20)
(5, 19)
(5, 18)
(6, 23)
(6, 24)
(6, 25)
(6, 26)
(6, 27)
(6, 28)
(6, 29)
(6, 30)
(6, 31)
(6, 32)
(6, 33)
(7, 36)
(7, 35)
(7, 34)
```

I'll leave the translation to arcpy up to you, but something like that should map well to using cursors.