# Slick phenomenon detection on point

Tags: qgis, python, r

I try treat vine data to detect frost or dryness. for the moment I have results as you can see in picture, tree groups of vines, healthy (green), weak(red) and missing (black). These 3 groups are respectively coded in a field with 2, 1 and 0. But I would like to make difference between lonely weak vine and slick of weak vines.

I'm able to use QGIS, Python, and a little bit R. So all your ideas with this 3 tools is good for me.

[>>Dataset<<](https://we.tl/FpblvmniQ9)

[image]

Comment: You could do a generalization. Convert points to raster with a coarse/medium resolution, make a density plot, heat map, and so on

Comment: My goal is to keep data as points.

Comment: So, create the raster with fractional of weak vines and extract attributes to preserve them in point layer (Zonal statistics in QGIS or `extract` in R). Use the information at symbol level

Comment: What do you mean by "lonely"? Any red spot with no red neighbours?

Comment: Can you provide an example dataset?

Comment: @Spacedman : exactly !

Comment: @Kersten : i'll add in my main post

Comment: @aldo_tapia : your idea is interesting but your explainations are to short for me.

Comment: Do you want to find groups only along the rows or in all directions?

Comment: @Kersten : all directions

Comment: I would go with a nearest neighbors approach. For each point, find the N nearest neighbors and the calculate the statistical mode of their class.

Comment: @AlexandreNeto : thank you great idea, i'll test it :)

Answer (score 3):

For only graphic purpose, create a new field, where weak are 1 and the other ones are 0. Use QGIS / heatmap to visualize them:

[image]

If you want to compute how dense are vine weak plants, create a raster (cell size will define the analysis area) with the field mentioned above as input value and extract information with point data (in R):

```
library(raster)
library(sp)
library(rgdal)

data <- read.csv('/path/to/FrostCluster.csv')

coordinates(data) <- ~X+Y

r <- raster(extent(data),ncol=50,nrow=50)

data$NewCluster2 <- ifelse(data@data$NewCluster == 1,1,0)

r <- rasterize(data,r,field='NewCluster2',fun=mean)

writeOGR(obj = extract(r,data,sp=T),dsn = '/path/to/',layer = 'test_vine',driver='ESRI Shapefile')
```

Use QGIS to visualize differences (1 value is a highly dense weak plants; 0 are healthy plants and no-data):

[image]

---

### Heatmap creation in QGIS:

[image]

Comment: What are your settings for heatmap ? I can't have same results as you.

Comment: My set in Symbology/heat map was: RdYlBu (inverted) color palette, a radius of 5 millimeters and pondered by the field created.

Comment: When I create my heat map, I didn't have same result as you... What are your settings for heat map creation ?

Comment: @GoMer I updated my answer adding the procedure to replicate the heatmap

Comment: Oh ok, i was using heat map plugin and not heat map symbology.

Comment: I try R script, it's really great. But i would like to change radius. Is it possible ? I don't know how because I can't understand `data$NewCluster2 <- ifelse(data@data$NewCluster == 1,1,0)`

Comment: `data$NewCluster2 <- ifelse(data@data$NewCluster == 1,1,0)` is to assing 1 to weak plants and 0 to the other one to a new column... prior to calculate the fractional weak plants... To change radius value, change `r <- raster(extent(data),ncol=50,nrow=50)`, you can set a unique resolution for ~x+y -`raster(extent(data),res=c(0.05,0.05))`- or change the number of columns and rows

Answer (score 2):

Read data, convert to sf spatial object, set CRS:

```
library(sf)
d = read.csv("./FrostCluster.csv",head=TRUE,as.is=TRUE)
d = st_as_sf(d, coords=c("X","Y"))
st_crs(d)=4326
plot(d[,"NewCluster"],pch=19)
```

Use `FNN` package to find the two nearest neighbours - I think two nearest neighbours makes more sense than just one for "loneliness":

```
library(FNN)
nn = knn.index(st_coordinates(d),k=2)
head(nn)
     [,1] [,2]
[1,]    2    3
[2,]    3    1
[3,]    2    4
[4,]    5    3
[5,]    4    6
[6,]    5    7
```

Now create new variables in the data holding the `NewCluster` value of the neighbours:

```
d$n1=d$NewCluster[nn[,1]]
d$n2=d$NewCluster[nn[,2]]
```

A "lonely" point is one where its `NewCluster` variable is different to its neighbours. Compute that as a new column:

```
d$lonely = (d$NewCluster != d$n1 ) & (d$NewCluster != d$n2)
plot(d[,"lonely"], pch=19)
```

[image]

Note that you get strings of "lonely" points because a set of alternating `NewCluster` values (like in the middle of 2-2-1-2-1-2-1-2-2) will probably show up as five "lonely" points. You might want to identify "lonely" points that are class 2 `NewColour`:

```
d$Lonely2 = d$lonely & d$NewCluster==2
table(d$Lonely2)

FALSE  TRUE 
 4128    65
```

That gives you 65 lonely plants of class 2.

You could extend this to more than two neighbours, depending on how lonely you want your points to be.

That answers the "lonely" point question, this idea of identifying "slicks" is **another** question and should probably be asked separately. Its not really well defined at the moment, unlike "lonely" which you said was dependent on differences to neighbours.

Answer (score 1):

You could assign two ids to each point, one for the line, one for the column. You can use the coordinates of your points so that their ids are ordered correctly (see [here](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/201306/numbering-adjacent-polygons-in-sequential-order) for example). This way you'll have a (virtual) grid that you can use to check if you have a least *n* points sharing the same color vertically and/or horizontally and/or diagonally. You'll actually end up with a problem similar to a "Connect 4" game - and you'll be able to find code samples for this easily (see [here](https://gist.github.com/poke/6934842), [here](https://www.reddit.com/r/learnprogramming/comments/2miank/connect_four_in_python/) or [here](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/120561/connect-four-in-python) for example).

Comment: In my datas each point have a row and vine number, that's cool. But as you can see in picture, row aren't aligned. So point 1-1 isn't aligned with 2-1. How can do a grid in this case...?

Comment: You can recreate a grid-like pattern using QGIS built-in "regular points" tool + "join attributes by location".

Comment: It's almost impossible my points are at same place that points of qgis regular points tool to do a spatial join. Isn't it ?

Comment: They don't need to be *exactly* at the same place: you can specify a precision (a tolerance) in your spatial join.