# Creating Unique IDs of points in order from west to east

Tags: arcgis-desktop, field-calculator, python-parser, unique-id, spatial-sort

I have a dataset with over 1000s points. I am wondering if I am able to give each point a unique ID starting from west to east.

I am using ArcMap 10.6. Is there a way to do this in ArcMap?

Comment: Calculate new field xcoordinate > sort by xcoordinate > add new numeric field "seq" > fill field seq with counter see: https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/193681/calculating-sequential-numbers-into-sorted-table-using-arcgis-desktop

Comment: A simple sort on easting and northing (descending) should work for this, though you might get more methodical results with large datasets if you use a grid to bin values first. See https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/73978/numbering-polygons-according-to-their-spatial-relationships

Comment: Check [How To: Create sequential numbers in a field using Python in the Field Calculator](https://support.esri.com/en/technical-article/000011137)

Comment: The solution in the link takes into account `OID` order, I guess.

Comment: The `Sort (management)` gp tool will produce a sorted fc.  You can set the sorting to be from left to right (cartesian). Then use the `Create sequential number using Calc Field` as stated above.

Answer (score 7):

First, to be sure `POINT_X` has no duplicate values, run next two lines in Python console.

```
# change layer_name
x_values = [row[0] for row in arcpy.da.SearchCursor("layer_name", "POINT_X")]
len(x_values) == len(set(x_values)) # output should be True
```

If `POINT_X` has no duplicate values you can use the following script in Field Calculator.

- Open `Field Calculator` (by right click on `seq` field)
- Populate the parameters as in the image using the following script. (Don't forget to change `layer_name` in the script)

  ```py
  x_values = [row[0] for row in arcpy.da.SearchCursor("layer_name", "POINT_X")]
  x_values.sort(reverse=True)

  def add_unique_ids(x):
      global x_values   
      i = x_values.index(x)   
      return i
  ```
- And call the method.

  ```
  add_unique_ids(!POINT_X!)
  ```

[image]

The main limitation is that features with the same `POINT_X` get the same `seq` value. I couldn't figure it out yet.

[image]

Comment: I'm not sure. Give it a try. I have set `seq` as integer.

Comment: Yes. I've tried something for duplicate values but I couldn't solve.

Comment: I  got that error. Make sure you typed the layer and field names in `SearchCursor`.

Comment: I think this is related to the data resolution, i.e., number of digits of X coordinate that you receive from ArcGIS and how they are saved in a python list. As a workaround, you can use `round` builtin function of python. In this answer, if you change `row[0]` to `round(row[0], 4)` and `x_values.index(x)` to `x_values.index(round(x ,4))`, you would be fine. Here, the value of 4 is arbitrary and presumed it will work in a projected CS.

Comment: I thought that. In your case, it would be fine. But it may return incorrect results for geographic coordinates.

Comment: you could also export the attribute table to excel, do a sort and sequence fill there and join the result based on fid